# basic bevel on cube not working

Tags: bevel

I am going through the tutorial and I'm on bevel (I'm a super newb)

I have the basic cube chose in the modeling editor

I click on the bevel tool and I click the left mouse button and drag to adjust the bevel.

An odd yellow post appears in the cube and all that happens is a rectangle selection box appears when I click the left button and drag the mouse.

thanks in advance,
Will

here's a pict of my screen. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The yellow handler is to make the bevel and you can select the edges that you wanna use[image]

Comment: Thanks! that did it. :) I guess it's a change from the 2.8 to the 2.83 version